# Add C++ redistribuitable in my .msi and install on silent

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, setup-project, silent-installer

I am working with a setup project of Visual Studio 2015. I want to distribute the 2015 C++ library, vc_redist.x86.exe. But I don't want user to be aware of this pre-requisite, so the idea is that while he is running the .msi, the C++ library will be auto-installed.
I have been reading about the merge modules, but this cannot fix my problem because the setup.exe should be run. Please, could anybody tell me how to deal with this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change (or create your own custom one) the standard bootstrapper that has documentation starting here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

The bootstrapper packages contain the detection and install logic for the redistributables. For example, the \Bootstrapper\Packages folder has VC redist folders, each with a product.xml and a package.xml about installing them as prerequisites. They have standard command lines such as:

Command PackageFile="vcredist_x64.exe" Arguments=' /q:a

and you can substitute that command with something like those listed here:

http://asawicki.info/news_1597_installing_visual_c_redistributable_package_from_command_line.html

that show the quiet options (as do standard Microsoft docs somewhere).